# UIPickerview in iphone

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode3.2

I am new to iphone. I am working on first application in iphone. I have a view, which contains an UIButton. when I clicked on this button, It will display UIPickerview. How can i do this? Can any one please tell me with proper example or sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad write

picker.hidden=TRUE;

and when you click on button make

```
picker.hidden=FALSE;
```

also you have to write picker's delegate methods for displaying data in it..

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion